# In ruby, how to create a method that has a options hash, and I can pass symbols to it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Article model (rails 3), I want to create methods that takes a parameter.

So I can do things like:

```
Article.get_by_id(:cache => true, :cache_expire => some_date)
```

I want to re-use this parameter, how can I do this?

The parameter is a hash of options, and I want to use it in many of my controllers methods.

Answer (score 2):

you can add following method to Article model

```
self.get_by_id(options = {}) 
cache = options['cache']
end
```

Now the parameter sent to the above method can be accessed using option hash. i.e, options['cache'] and options['cache_expired'].

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
custom_options = { :cache => true, :cache_expire => some_date }
Article.get_by_id(custom_options)
```

I'm sorry if I am not getting you but your question was very brief.